# Can I constraint a generic type parameter to only accept types implementng a particular generic interface and access the IF type parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, syntax, generic-constraints

What I seek to do is that define a generic type `ClassB<TA>` that would accept the `TA` type parameter to be assigned any type implementing a generic interface `IInterfaceA<TB>` but *in whatever a way* [the interface definition allows], regardless the type parameter `TB` that has been passed to it (`IInterfaceA`) in the `TA` implementation. I would also like to be able to access the type parameter (`TB`) that has actually been passed to the `IInterfaceA` interface by the particular `TA` implementation being used in the `ClassB<TA>` definition. Is this possible in C#? If yes, then what is the correct syntax?

E.g. something like the following (not particularly useful though seemingly illustrating, I hope) but syntactically and semantically correct:

```
public interface IInterfaceA<TB>
{
    TB TheProperty {get; set;}
}

public class ClassB<TA> where TA : IInterfaceA<TB>
{
    TA TheProperty {get; set;}

    TB ThePropertyProperty => TheProperty.TheProperty;
}
```

UPDATE: I have actually went the following way so far (before having decided to ask if a better one may happen to exist), including `TB` (The `IInterfaceA` type parameter) itself in the definition of the `ClassB` but I am still curious if `ClassB` can be defined the way that would just allow all `IInterfaceA` implementations and derive/import the `IInterfaceA` type parameter a way implicitly (not 100% sure but seems actually making logically-definite (non-ambiguous) strong-typing sense while increasing code reusability to me, that's why I have guessed such a feature has a chance to actually exist).

```
public class ClassB<TA, TB> where TA : IInterfaceA<TB>
{
    TA TheProperty {get; set;}

    TB ThePropertyProperty => TheProperty.TheProperty;
}
```

UPDATE2: Given the original example and an example of an existing alternative provided it can probably be worth emphasizing on that a particular type meant (by an actual application design) to be assigned to the TA parameter at the instance definition time can happen to be a non-generic class, a completely-defined implementation of IInterfaceA with TB assignment hardcoded in its source (because no other types can make sense to be used instead of it in the context of particular-case logic parts this specific class implements perhaps), excepting no type arguments already (and I feel that what has already been defined should be referenced rather than re-defined a potentially "I remember it has been assigned X the last time" kind of way, for sake of avoiding creating soil for bugs and errors to emerge on at least, not to mention aesthetics/readability, maintainability, eliminating needs for copy-paste definitions of logical analogues targeting slightly different cases etc). The alternative solution mentioned means explicitly defining what is rather straight-forward to be unambiguously figured out by the compiler (at least in cases when the same interface is not implemented twice with different type arguments, thanks to @vyrp for highlighting the possibility of ambiguity in the multiple implementation case) given the usage context (what I consider not only a way handier, but also less bug-prone) and limiting the generic code re-usage opportunities. I believe this remark can explain why a less-verbose alternative to the `ClassB<TA, TB> where TA : IInterfaceA<TB>` syntax (as a way of implementing the logic described above) can make sense to seek at all.

Comment: What is "IF type parameters"?

Comment: You aren't declaring `TB`. It's not clear to me whether that's a mistake or if not declaring it is precisely what you are asking about, because I don't follow what you are asking at all.

Comment: And what do you think `T` should be in `ClassB<TA> where T : IInterfaceA<TB>`? It has to be `TA`, but where is the `TB` coming from?

Comment: @Enigmativity "IF" = "interface" in this question. I just have failed to fit in the question title length limit without using the abbreviation. Sorry. I am going to update the question to compensate the title quality...

Comment: UPDATE: I've added an explanation to the beginning of the question body and made some minor corrections in the example code.

Comment: I've added an answer with an example to show that what you want is not possible.

Comment: @Ivan - I can't even hope to understand your first sentence in UPDATE2. It's nearly 1,000 characters long. I think you need to work on shorter and clearer explanations.

Comment: @enigmativity Thanks you for constructive feedback! I really appreciate it. Just have a habit of trying best to write as definitively (i.e. formally, as if I were coding) as possible in hope to make the chance of misunderstanding as small as possible, clearly some times our efforts result in an opposite of what we intend :-)

Comment: If you are dealing with n different generic types you have to declare **all** of them (<T1,..,Tn>). There is no shortcut or magic powder to get around that fact.

Answer (score 4):

The most immediate way to make this compile is this:

```
public interface IInterfaceA<T>
{
    T TheProperty {get; set;}
}

public class ClassB<TA, TB> where TA : IInterfaceA<TB>
{
    TA TheProperty {get; set;}

    TB ThePropertyProperty => TheProperty.TheProperty;
}
```

But I'm not sure that I follow exactly what you're asking.

---

I'm not sure if this is what you mean by "nicer", but sometimes you can use a static outer class to allow one generic parameter to be inferred while explicitly providing the other:

```
public static class Helper<TB>
{
    public static ClassB<TA> Create<TA>() where TA : IInterfaceA<TB>
    {
        return new ClassB<TA>();
    }

    public class ClassB<TA> where TA : IInterfaceA<TB>
    {
        TA TheProperty { get; set; }

        TB ThePropertyProperty => TheProperty.TheProperty;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the way I've actually used so far. Just curious if a nicer way exists. Thanks anyway. I am going give others some time and  accept your question if (most probably, I feel) nothing that can be considered "a nicer way" will get offered.

Comment: @Ivan - Can you explain what you mean by "a nicer way"?

Comment: I mean less redundant and more flexible. A particular type to be assigned to the TA parameter at the instance definition time can happen to be a non-generic class, a completely-defined implementation of IInterfaceA<TB> with TB assignment hardcoded in its source, excepting no type arguments already (and I feel that what has already been defined should be referenced rather than re-defined, for sake of avoiding creating soil for bugs and errors to emerge on at least, not to mention aesthetics/readability).

Comment: The solution we have both chosen so far means explicitly defining what is rather straight-forward to be unambiguously figured out by the compiler given the usage context and and limiting the generic code re-usage opportunities.

Comment: @Ivan - The code doesn't have any redundancy. Can you show me an example where you think that it does?

Answer (score 1):

In UPDATE2, the PO says: "straight-forward to be unambiguously figured out by the compiler".

I beg to differ.

Let's suppose you have a class like this:

```cs
public class Impl : IInterfaceA<int>, IInterfaceA<string>
{
    public int TheProperty { get; set; }
    string IInterfaceA<string>.TheProperty { get; set; }
}
```

If you call `ClassB<Impl>`, what should `TB` be then?

---

That being said, let's dive in one possible implementation.

WARNING: this is not good-practice code! It is only supposed to show the mechanics of the language. The answer by @Enigmativity is how I would do it (aka, writing `ClassB<TA, TB> where TA : IInterfaceA<TB>`).

An option could be to define a base non-generic `IInterfaceA`. The tradeoff would be that `ThePropertyProperty` would have to be `object`.

Let be the definitions:

```cs
public interface IInterfaceA
{
    object TheProperty {get; set;}
}

public interface IInterfaceA<TB> : IInterfaceA
{
    new TB TheProperty {get; set;}
}

public class ClassB<TA> where TA : IInterfaceA
{
    public TA TheProperty {get; set;}

    public object ThePropertyProperty => TheProperty.TheProperty;

    // You can choose to write here either "IInterfaceA`1" or typeof(IInterfaceA<>).Name
    public Type TypeOfTB => typeof(TA).GetInterface("IInterfaceA`1").GetGenericArguments()[0];
}

public class Impl : IInterfaceA<int>
{
    public int TheProperty { get; set; }

    object IInterfaceA.TheProperty
    {
        get { return TheProperty; }
        set { TheProperty = (int)value; }
    }
}
```

Then the following code compiles and runs successfully:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var impl = new Impl{ TheProperty = 42 };
    int i = impl.TheProperty;
    Console.WriteLine(i);

    var b = new ClassB<Impl>{ TheProperty = impl };
    i = (int)b.ThePropertyProperty;
    Console.WriteLine(i);

    Console.WriteLine(b.TypeOfTB.Name);
}
```

With output:

```
42
42
Int32
```

For bonus I've added how to get TB at runtime.

Comment: Thanks. But isn't this kind of of weak typing (using the `object` type unless necessary) meant to be avoided at all reasonable costs when coding in a strongly-typed language like C#?

Comment: Yes, it should be avoided. I was just trying to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you one more time, @vyrp, I sincerely appreciate your contribution, just wanted to make it clear so others probably going to visit this Q&A in future won't mistakenly get an idea of this being a normal practice (or to make sure I'm not the only one keeping away from this having a wrong idea myself :-)).

Comment: Added a warning.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, don't you also think you probably should migrate your other answer  (the one rightfully arguing unambiguity) to either inside of this one (I like this option better as it would keep well-visible then) or a comment to the question? It is a great thing to mention while I worry an occasional moderator can disagree it is a real answer (feels a way more like a good comment, indeed) and choose to remove it.

Comment: I didn't put as a comment because it was too big. I'm going to move it here then.